# jersey and additional data for json reply without modifying the entity class

Tags: java, json, jersey

Let's say I have a `person` class with only 2 attributes, `name` and `age`. My json reply using `jersey` will give me something like that.

```
{
    "name":"john",
    "age":"21"
}
```

Is there a way to add in additional information into the json reply without modifying the entity itself. Let's say if I want the reply to be:

```
{
    "name":"john",
    "age":"21"
    "favcolor":"red"
}
```

Let's say `favcolor` is retrieved from a db or something and is not a attribute of the `person` class. Is it possible to do something like this?

Comment: you could inherit your exist person class, and add the additional attributes.

Answer (score 1):

From the REST client point of view, it doesn't matter how a Resource Represenation is build. If you use JAX-RS, Jersey, and JAXB, the recommended way is to make the class annotated with `@XmlRootElement` match the returned Resource Represenation.

I your example this would be something like this:

```
@XmlRootElement
class Person {
  private String name;
  private String age;
  private String favcolor;

  // Constuctor, Getter, Setter
}
```

This class that is serialized to JSON is not necessarily the same class that is retrieved from some backend.

**Answer:** There is no way I know of and I don't recommend to do what you ask.

Comment: doesn't jersey have a responsebuilder or something

Comment: @LionelKoh A [`Response.ResponseBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.ResponseBuilder.html) builds the HTTP Response (status, headers) but not the content. The content is build by a [JAX-RS Entity Providers](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/message-body-workers.html). The easiest way to build a Response body is to use JAXB annotated class like I've sketched above.